# Make background Video with HTml5

Tags: css, html, video

On my new project I will be putting the first section of my website background video.

It's awesome, I read some articles and I found this tutorial: [Example](http://www.pencilscoop.com/2013/12/awesome-full-page-video-effects-with-html5/), but all the  tutorials and articles make the video for all the screen size 100% height. I just wanna make it for the first section only and the user can scroll after that. like this [example](http://google.com/nexus/index.html)

I think that the problem is in the **CSS**:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
min-width: 50%;
min-height: 50%;
```

Comment: Did you forget the `z-index`? Can you create a Fiddle or something?

Comment: check this website, hope it will help you. http://www.google.com/nexus/index.html

Comment: @putvande Please Check the live demo
http://www.pencilscoop.com/demos/video_bg/index.html

Comment: @KheemaPandey , that`s all i need  :D :D how you make something like that ????? Great example

Comment: maybe be this can help,

http://demosthenes.info/blog/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video

Comment: @Mohamed do you want to me make it for you?

Comment: @KheemaPandey no sorry , i just wanna know how i can make it ? thats all

Comment: I'll explain to you in 1/2 an hour

Comment: @KheemaPandey i cant wait to  see your explain :D :D thanks man

Comment: @KheemaPandey , where your explain please

Comment: I've made a sample example now, please take a look. http://jsbin.com/guporaga/3